# Friendly URL for a custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, jroute

I'm trying to create a friendly URL for a custom component but i can't manage to find a solution.
I have tried JRoute but it hasn't worked out for me (probably i'm not doing it right). Does anybody have any idea? I have created the router file and i read the documentation but i couldn't understand.

```
place?id=113?cat=3
```

i wanted it to be

```
place/113/3
```

UPDATE:

after implementing all methods i get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to ComponentRouter::__construct() must be an
>   instance of CMSApplication or null

My code is:

```
class ContentRouter implements Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterInterface

{   

    public function __construct(CMSApplication $app = null, AbstractMenu $menu = null)
    {
        $category = new RouterViewConfiguration('category');
        $category->setKey('id')->setNestable();
        $this->registerView($category);
        $article = new RouterViewConfiguration('article');
        $article->setKey('id')->setParent($category, 'catid');
        $this->registerView($darticle);

        parent::__construct($app, $menu);

        $this->attachRule(new MenuRules($this));
        $this->attachRule(new StandardRules($this));
        $this->attachRule(new NomenuRules($this));
    }

    /* the other methods go here

}
```

I'm not sure if `Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterInterface` is the right class to be implement since there's no many examples but i followed along with the tutorial, i have implemented all the 3 methods and i yet get that error.

Comment: Please don't edit just to change `i` to `I`, but if you make any more meaningful edits, please improve the grammar in the same edit.

Comment: Sorry, sometimes i don't realise my mistakes and then i come to correct some minor errors. By the way, if you have any idea i will be very much appreciated.

Comment: No worries, I will guide you through your early days here.  As for your issue, I will leave you in the very capable hands of Sharky.

Comment: Some more info on the new router at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/YnILNx_Lmeg. If you can't get it to work, then you can always try going back to the old router. A simple example using it is in https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_alias#Router_2. (I tried getting the new router to work for my component, but failed).

Comment: I'm glad i'm not the only one. I have seen some people complaining about it. Honestly, someone needs to update the documentation.

Comment: @Thiago, yeah, in my opinion, the big problem with a rule-based router like the new Joomla one is that it's pretty impossible to debug if you can't get it to work. If you're in that position then I'd recommend going with the old one. At least it's going to be possible to get it working in the end of the day.

Comment: I have tried the one you recomended and worked isntantly without having to do any modification. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a router for your component for `JRoute::_()` to do anything. See [Supporting SEF URLs in your component](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component) documentation. I suggest looking specifically at [Simple View-based Example](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component#A_Simple_View-based_Example) which uses a new way of working with routing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i had tried this and i had no success. The documention isn't clear to me (it might work out for others) but i have had hard times trying to understand the content of that page. I found that quite unhelpful. It didn't even say the class i should extend. I tried to implement the functions and always get an error such as abstract class errors and so on.

Comment: I tried to implement the `Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterInterface` class but it gives me an error `ComponentRouter contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods` i don't know what methods are those.

Comment: I mean it says the name of the methods but how can i implement them? There's no example.

Comment: I have implement the methods but it gives me another error `Argument 1 passed to ComponentRouter::__construct() must be an instance of CMSApplication or null, instance of Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication given in...libraries\src\Router\SiteRouter.php on line 785`

Comment: If you want to use standard routing, the class to extend is `Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterView`. This is written in the linked documentation.

Comment: I have tried exteding the `Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterView` class and implementing `Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterInterface` interface. Both gives me the same error: `Argument 1 passed to ComponentRouter::__construct() must be an instance of CMSApplication or null, instance of Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication given in...libraries\src\Router\SiteRouter.php on line 785`

Comment: You need to import some classes like `Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication`.

Comment: Oh  sure, forgive my ignorance and thank you very much.

Comment: I made a modification because i was getting an error (call to udefined method registerView) even importing all classes. Instead of implementing the class `Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterInterface`  i extended the class `Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterViewConfiguration`. Does it work out? It's not giving me any errors.